# Rselenium でブラウザが起動しない

Tags: r, web-scraping, selenium

Rseleniumを使用したいのですがwebブラウザを開く段階でエラーが出てしまいました。

エラーメッセージ

```
Selenium message:Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-8QSKR3I', ip: '192.168.0.23', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_381'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

コード

```
#install.packages("RSelenium")
library(rvest) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(data.table)
library(RSelenium) 
library(lubridate) 
library(stringi) 

setwd("ファイル") 

#selenium.jarの起動
system("java -jar selenium.jar &")

#Google Chrome 起動
SelChr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(port = 4444L, browserName = "chrome")

#Webブラウザを開く
SelChr$open() #Chromeが立ち上がれば成功
```

Comment: WebDriverがインストールされていないか、そこへのPATHが通っていないとかでは？ [RSeleniumを使うために必要なファイルとインストール方法](https://walkintheforest.net/rselenium-setting/), [R言語のRSeleniumを使って、ブラウザ（自動）操作とWeb ...](https://skume.net/entry/2021/04/04/233140)